# IQueryable timeout expired

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, sql-server-2016

I have a problem with the query to the database.
When i try code below, it works 75ms and return empty List. Everything is ok.

```
var test1 = unit
    .PersonQualities.GetAll()
    .Where(qp => qp.QualityId == qualityId && qp.PersonId == targetPersonId)
    .ToList();
```

But when i use this, it works 30sec and return timeout expired exception:

```
var test2 = unit
    .PersonQualities.GetAll()
    .FirstOrDefault(qp => qp.QualityId == qualityId && qp.PersonId == targetPersonId);
```

My GetAll method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    return Entities.AsQueryable();
}
```

Please explain why this happens. And what can i do for fix this issue. Thanks.
P.S. I`m using SQL Server 2016 Developer. Both queries works in SSMS.

FirstOrDefault query in profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value], 
    [Extent1].[Percent] AS [Percent], 
    [Extent1].[IsLocked] AS [IsLocked], 
    [Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
    [Extent1].[QualityId] AS [QualityId]
    FROM [dbo].[PersonQuality] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[QualityId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[PersonId] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 bigint,@p__linq__1 bigint',@p__linq__0=110207,@p__linq__1=43257113
```

SingleOrDefault:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value], 
    [Extent1].[Percent] AS [Percent], 
    [Extent1].[IsLocked] AS [IsLocked], 
    [Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
    [Extent1].[QualityId] AS [QualityId]
    FROM [dbo].[PersonQuality] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[QualityId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[PersonId] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 bigint,@p__linq__1 bigint',@p__linq__0=110207,@p__linq__1=43257113
```

Comment: Have you tried running the queries directly on your database server?

Comment: @Jehof no, i cant do it at the moment(

Comment: SingleOrDefault works fine :\

Comment: 1. Edit your question to include **which** flavour of SQL you're using. 2. You can look at the generated SQL queries by inspecting the code while debugging, just before you materialise the query into objects.

Comment: @J. Steen FirstOrDefault instantly materializes a request to an object, or not?

Comment: @OldUnion ToList, FirstOrDefault, SingleOrDefault all materialise requests.

Comment: @J. Steen how can I look at the generated SQL queries by inspecting the code while debugging, if ToList, FirstOrDefault, SingleOrDefault all materialise requests instantly?

The SQL Profiler showed me the same requests. The difference for FirstOrDefault - SELECT TOP (1), SingleOrDefault - SELECT TOP (2).

Comment: @mjwills yes, same variable same type of object. Which variable populate first is not important, because (test2) always unsuccessful and throw exception.

Comment: @OldUnion If you run `DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB` and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql against the database does that make any of the queries faster / slower?

Comment: @mjwills
it fixed my problem, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you need to update your statistics and flush your query caches.

```
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB
```

and

```
UPDATE STATISTICS
```

may help.